# break with ||, && in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Powershell now supports `||` and `&&`. But when I try this:

```
while ($true) { my_command.exe || break }
```

I get an error that

```
break: The term 'break' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
```

So, what is the simple, short, convenient way to achieve the same effect as in Bash:

```
while :; do my_command || break; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> while ($true) { my_command.exe || break }

The operators `||` and `&&` are not principally PowerShell operators,
but are rather batch commands, more related to DOS/CMD than PowerShell.
These operators check the error code returned by an executable for
success (0) or failure (not 0).

The command `break` is not a DOS/CMD command, but is rather a pure
PowerShell command, mainly relating to the flow of control of loop
or switch commands.

I assume that this is why your attempt to combine syntactical
constructs from two different worlds, DOS/CMD and PowerShell,
has failed in this first formulation.

> while ($true) { my_command.exe || $(break) }

In this second formulation from your answer, your have used the `$()` operator.
This operator evaluates and executes a PowerShell expression.
The `break` command was then evaluated by PowerShell, not by DOS/CMD,
which was now able to execute it correctly and terminate the while loop.

Comment: Why `(break)` does not work, only `$(break)`? `(...)` executes `...` too, right? So, why the dollar is required?

Comment: With parenthesis, you're still in the DOS/CMD world, so it's DOS/CMD that is interpreting the command. But DOS/CMD knows nothing about `while` or `break`. The `$()` command calls the PowerShell interpreter to understand the expression, so it's PowerShell that can understand the `break`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer:

```
while ($true) { my_command.exe || $(break) }
```

But I don't know why it's correct.